# cannot click on the clickbox with web automation selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

using this line in my python selenium code, and it cannot find the clickbox to click

```
agreeone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ulappointmentInfo"]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/input[1]')

agreeone.click()
```

the inspect yields

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try some of these solutions:

1 -
Validate behind your browser if the input path is correct, use F12 in Chrome for that, then use the command (Ctrl + Shift + C) to enter the element selection mode after that, select the element and click, after that with your right mouse button Copy> Copy xpath, Copy full xpath, test with the 2 to see if this is the problem.

2 -
Test if the element really exists on the page for example use the following algorithm:

```
 def check_exists_by_xpath (self, xpath):
     try:
         self.driver.find_element_by_xpath (xpath)
     except NoSuchElementException:
         return False
     return True
```